# How to store only .yml files in Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Im trying to get to set a validation on the storing .yml files only.
With some research I'm doing this:

```
class TranslationFile < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
  validate :only_yml_type

  private
  def only_yml_type
    if file.attached? && !file.content_type.in?(%w(application/x-yaml)) 
      file.purge
      errors.add(:file, 'Must be a yaml file')
    end
  end
end
```

but now even if the file is .yml / .yaml I can't  store it, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/13dd38cee79be39f7b399e142fd78295dddd2abb/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_types.rb#L23

Try also `text/yaml`

Comment: @FrederikSpang It still doesn't work :/

Comment: Can you try to output `file.content_type` there, and just see what comes out?

Comment: @FrederikSpang I've tried it and it gives me: "application/x-yaml"